# Problems defining an array in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

I'm trying to define an array using the following code:

```
data all_dates;
  array arr[*] _temporary_ (1 2 3 4 5);
run;
```

It gives me this message:

```
ERROR: The non-variable based array arr has been defined with zero elements.
```

Looking at [the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201956.htm) examples I can't see why this wouldn't work.  Am I doing something wrong or is this just not allowed?  If it's not allowed what is an alternative equivalent method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah nevermind - the documentation actually does state:

```
You cannot use the asterisk with _TEMPORARY_ arrays or when you define a multidimensional array.
```

I guess I'll have to count the number of elements I'll need beforehand and then use:

```
data all_dates;
  array arr[*] a1-a5 (1 2 3 4 5);
  drop a1-a5;
run;
```

Comment: Why do you need to use an asterisk there?

Comment: I was just being lazy =) You're right - I could explicitly state `5` or `1:5` in the sizing, but in my code the iterator is just counting from `lbound()` to `ubound()` anyway.

Comment: You don't even need to do that.  The statement `array arr a1-a5` is perfectly legal without any count.  If you explicitly define the array members, SAS figures out the count.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of that... Also I should correct my previous comment - there's no `ubound()` function in SAS it's `hbound()`.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution with temporary arrays is to over-define the temporary array.  Since it's not in the PDV, and not written out (obviously), you can simply define it for 50 or 100 or whatever is a safe number above your maximum - it won't cost almost any performance to do so.

Alternately, if the 'safe number' is too large for your desired memory allocation (say, tens of thousands), use a macro variable and precount the number.  Given that you wrote out

```
(1 2 3 4 5)
```

You should be able to count the number of needed variables when you create this list.